# Matplotlib to Create histogram by Row

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have three arrays that essentially correspond to a matrix of gene expression values and then column labels specifying condition IDs and row values specifying a specific gene. I'm trying to define a function that will plot a histogram by just providing the gene name.

[image]

Basically I need to specify YAL001C and create a histogram of the values across the row. I'm very new to matplotlib and I'm not sure how do this. Would it have something to do with using something like an np.where(gene = YAL001C) argument? I guess I'm just not sure where that would fit into code for matplotlib.

I currently have the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
def histogram(gene):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    x = np.where(geneList == gene, exprMat)
    bins = 50
    ax.hist(x, bins, color = 'green', edgecolor = 'black', alpha = 0.8 )
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you mean bar graph when you say histogram?

Comment: If so, you have two questions: (1) how to identify/extract row, (2) how to make a bar graph. Both have been asked many times on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to avoid using **pandas**, you can still accomplish what you want using **numpy**, but you need to add some codes to figure out what row corresponds to a given gene. Here is one of the ways you could code it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[0.15, -0.22, 0.07],
                 [-0.07, -0.76, -0.12],
                 [-1.22, -0.27, -0.1],
                 [-0.09, 1.2, 0.16]
                ])

def plot_hist(gene):
    
    list_genes = ['YAL001C', 'YAL002W', 'YAL003W', 'YAL004W']
    if gene in list_genes:
        sn_gene = list_genes.index(gene)
    else:
        print(f'{gene} is not in the list of genes')
        return
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
    plt.hist(data[sn_gene,:])
    plt.title(f'gene: {gene}')
    plt.show()
    
plot_hist('YAL001C')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways you could accomplish that (passing the data related to the corresponding row to the method):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[0.15, -0.22, 0.07],
                 [-0.07, -0.76, -0.12],
                 [-1.22, -0.27, -0.1],
                 [-0.09, 1.2, 0.16]
                ])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, 
                  index=['YAL001C', 'YAL002W', 'YAL003W', 'YAL004W'], 
                  columns=['cln3-1', 'cln3-2', 'clb'])
print(df)

def plot_hist(gene):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(9,4))
    ax[0].bar(df.columns, df.loc[gene])
    ax[1].hist(df.loc[gene])
    plt.show()
    
plot_hist('YAL001C')
```

**Left: bar-plot, Right: histogram**

[image: Left: bar-plot, Right: histogram]

Comment: I'm actually trying to define a function that takes the gene name though and provides a histogram across the row. This is not a function and is down vertically.

Comment: I added a function accordingly, but don't know what you mean by "... is down vertically". Do you need a horizontal bar-plot? Besides, drawing histogram does not make much sense for three data points. I assume you have more data points in each row...

Comment: It's only a snippet of the data. There are 86 columns in total, which I will not post here. The histogram needs to reflect values across the row. How would I do this without using the pandas module, if I may ask? I was trying to write a function only using numpy and was running into issues related to selecting the specific gene. I was trying to subset, but was not able to do so using a string value.

Comment: I decided to leave this solution as is, in case it can help others in future. I added another solution without using pandas to meet your requirements.